# How do you get specific firebase data without knowing the unique id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I have some data in my firebase database that I want to retrieve. I did one big push so that all instances would have a unique id. I know want to retrieve this data

I know I can do this:

`var gymData = firebase.database().ref('gymData/previousWorkouts')`

but when I get returned data like this:

[image]

how the hell am I suppose to access that id without knowing it?

for example a user of my app is going to search for an exercise and update it. they search by name, how do I find that id and look inside there? I don't get it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref('gymData/exrcises').orderByChild('name').equal("barbell bench press").once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;//this is id 
  });
});
```